# opkg vs apt on openWrt

Tags: linux, router, openwrt, apt, opkg

I am currently in the process of building a Raspberry Pi router which also runs an apache2 webserver and an FTP server.

Instead of apt, which I am used to, I have to use opkg. So I wondered, what are the differences between both package managers, how does opkg differenciate itself from ipkg and dpkg and is it somehow possible, to get apt running on openWrt?

Answer (score 0):

`dpkg` has a different syntax than `apt` except for the very basic

```
# Install a package
opkg update
opkg install <package>
```

Some useful commands

```
# List available packages
opkg list <*string*>
 
# List installed packages
opkg list-installed

# List installed and upgradable packages
opkg list-upgradable

# Display package information
opkg info <package>
```

I was not able to find the help command, but just typing `dpkg` listed all commands and options. Also a useful description page can be fount at [OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/additional-software/opkg).